# django move data from local to production?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I will be doing most of my data populating locally before deploying so I need a good solution for moving the data into the production db. Strangely I can't seem to find much info about this. I am trying to work through doing it manually with postgre right now from what I have searched.

Is there a quick and dirty method to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-app-label-app-label-app-label-model)/[`loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#loaddata-fixture-fixture) management commands:

On local machine:

```
python manage.py dumpdata > mydata.json
```

On production:

```
python manage.py loaddata mydata.json
```

Comment: wow seems easy, can't believe I missed that in my research. I'll try it later today when I have a chance, thanks

Comment: no help if data is already on production and you added few rows on dev in configuration table (like added new category), but on prod there are a lot of edits (like new orders)